# Using Form Action within loaded php-File

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms

I'm currently trying to make a Website a little more dynamic but I ran into a problem. 
I've got my index.php, which contains some links and a DIV-Container. I'm loading a php-File into the DIV using jQuery.

index.php:

```
                            <li><a href="#bestand">Bestand</a></li>
            </nav>
            <div id="main" style="text-align:center">

              <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
              <script type="text/javascript"> 
              var main = $("#main");
              $(window).on('hashchange', function() {
                  var href = location.hash.slice(1) +".php";
                  main.load(href);
              });
              </script> 

            </div>
```

The php-File (bestand.php) has a form to filter the results:

```
echo "<form action='bestand.php' method='post'>";


            $stid = oci_parse($conn, 'SELECT distinct SID FROM TB_XXXX ORDER BY SID');
            oci_execute($stid);
            echo "<select name='sid'>";
            echo "<option>SID</option>";
            while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
                echo "<option>\n";
                foreach ($row as $item) {
                    echo ($item !== null ? htmlentities($item, ENT_QUOTES) : "&nbsp;");
                }
                echo "</option>\n";
            }
            echo "</select>";
            echo "<input type='submit' value='Senden'/>";
            echo "</form>";
```

Loading the the php-File into the DIV-Containerworks perfectly, but as soon as I use the Form to filter the results the bestand.php opens with the filtered Result. I can't figure out, how to direct the result to the DIV-Container in the index.php.

Answer (score 0):

What I understood is you are trying to insert php file using javascript, Since php is executed at server level when you load php file using javascript client doesn't understand what php is so you will get raw file loaded into your di. My suggestion is include `bestand.php` into `inde.php` using php include method. Below is the example code for including one php file into another `<?php include 'basetand.php';?>`